# Finding mean of 5000 different csvs to summarize in one python list

Tags: python, pandas, coding-efficiency

I have a folder with about 5000 csvs with 60,000 rows and 10 columns in each. I wish to obtain mean of each csv and append it to a list. Current code below:

```
mean_list = []
   
for item in train_frags: # train_frags is a variable that holds location of all files
    segment = pd.read_csv(item,dtype = 'Int16')
    mean_list.append(segment.mean())
```

This code has been running for more than 10 minutes now!!. Please suggest an efficient version.

Comment: There's no solution that doesn't involve reading every single byte, and I'd guess you're bottlenecked by disk I/O rather than CPU, so I don't think there's a whole lot you can do to optimize (other than pre-processing/caching so that if you need to do it again you don't have to start from scratch each time).  Can you put this folder on a faster disk, or perhaps even spread it across multiple physical disks so you could parallelize the reads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only real thing I can think of is that you are using append, which is pretty slow, so maybe try to convert it to list comprehension if possible. The only other thing I can think of is to use numba (https://numba.pydata.org/), which could help with performance and speed.